# How to use forEachFeatureAtPixel() to display feature data in overlay for 2 different layers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have one point vector layer and one polygon vector layer.
I have created an overlay for each data source:

> ```
>     <div class="map" id="map">
>         <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
>             <p class="popup-text">Amenity: </p><span class="popup-data" id="feature-amenity"></span><br>
>             <p class="popup-text">Brand: </p><span class="popup-data" id="feature-brand"></span><br>
>             <p class="popup-text">Name: </p><span class="popup-data" id="feature-name"></span><br>
>             <p class="popup-text">Shop: </p><span class="popup-data" id="feature-shop"></span><br>
>         </div>
>         <div id="popup-zonas" class="ol-popup">
>             <p class="popup-text">Hab: </p><span class="popup-data" id="feature-hab"></span><br>
>             <p class="popup-text">Nº comercios: </p><span class="popup-data" id="feature-comercios"></span><br>
>             <p class="popup-text">Ratio: </p><span class="popup-data" id="feature-ratio"></span><br>
>         </div>
>     </div>
> ```

When clicking on features of any of the layers, it always pops up the same feature info (polygon layer related). You click on a polygon feature, you get the polygon data. You click on a point, you get the polygon underlying data.
Why is this happening? Why I dont get point data in the overlay?

I wrote a function for an event click for each layer.
Note the differentiating layerFilter function.
Each callback function has also a different interaction extension.

Shouldn´t disthinguish what info to display?

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
    map.addOverlay(popupComercios);
    popupComercios.setPosition(undefined);
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature){
        let clickedCoord = e.coordinate;
        let clickedFeatureAmenity = feature.get('amenity');
        let clickedFeatureBrand = feature.get('brand');
        let clickedFeatureName = feature.get('name');
        let clickedFeatureShop = feature.get('shop');
        popupZonas.setPosition(clickedCoord);
        overlayFeatureAmenity.innerHTML = clickedFeatureAmenity;
        overlayFeatureBrand.innerHTML = clickedFeatureBrand;
        overlayFeatureName.innerHTML = clickedFeatureName;
        overlayFeatureShop.innerHTML = clickedFeatureShop;
        map.setView(new View({
            center: clickedCoord,
            zoom: 15
        }))
        map.getInteractions().extend([selectInteractionComercios]);
    }, {
        layerFilter: function (layer) {
            return layer === comerciosVector;
        }
    })
})

map.on('click', function(e) {
    map.addOverlay(popupZonas);
    popupZonas.setPosition(undefined);
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(e.pixel, function(feature){
        let clickedCoord = e.coordinate;
        let clickedFeatureHab = feature.get('habitantes');
        let clickedFeatureComercios = feature.get('num_comercios');
        let clickedFeatureRatio = feature.get('ratio');
        popupZonas.setPosition(clickedCoord);
        overlayFeatureHab.innerHTML = clickedFeatureHab;
        overlayFeatureComercios.innerHTML = clickedFeatureComercios;
        overlayFeatureRatio.innerHTML = clickedFeatureRatio;
        map.setView(new View({
            center: clickedCoord,
            zoom: 15
        }))
        map.getInteractions().extend([selectInteractionZonas]);         
    }, {
        layerFilter: function (layer) {
            return layer === zonasVector;
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of OpenLayers (6.4.3)?

Comment: Are you sure that the popups don't simply overlap? the click handler for the zonas-layer is added second, so it will trigger after the points layer. As a side note: you are adding an interaction inside `forEachFeatureAtPixel`, which will add the same interaction multiple times when features of the same layer overlap at the clicked pixel

Comment: I just deleted a blury comment I did. Hope this helps to get out of question ban